# Failed to convert dataframe from pandas to R

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-mining, rpy2

I tried to convert dataframe form pandas to R, but one of column (HPS) should be numeric instead converted into string

here the function i use to converting dataframe pandas to R

```
def convert_pd_to_rdf(data):
        with localconverter(ro.default_converter + ro.pandas2ri.converter):
            data_r = ro.conversion.py2ri(data)
        return data_r
```

here the code for converting dataframe to pandas to R

```
X_train_r = convert_pd_to_rdf(X_train_)
```

here X_train_ and X*_*train_r dataframe

[X_train_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erqaj.png)

[X_train_r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syMVp.png)

error like this also appears

```
C:\Users\ASUS\miniconda3\envs\dt_bpbj_rpy\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py:67: UserWarning: Error while trying to convert the column "HPS". Fall back to string conversion. The error is: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.SexpVector'> returned a result with an error set
  (name, str(e)))
```

Before this i used onehot encoder and it worked, but my teacher said to try not to use onehot encoder and compare the results

Also i'm new to this, i would appreciate any help

Sorry for my bad English

Thank You

Comment: This may be due to the presence of non-numeric characters or missing values in the column HPS. You can try to identify and fix any issues with the "HPS" column in your pandas DataFrame before attempting to convert it to R again.

Comment: i already checked many times, there is no non-numeric character or missing values in the column HPS